# Publishing of Qt application in Windows 10 Store both for x86 and arm7 platforms

Tags: c++, qt, windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-10

**Target**: Determine working way to publish Qt5 application in Windows 10 Store both for Windows 10 Desktop and Mobile device families.
**Issue**: Qt5 WinRT provides separate Qt builds for x86, x64 and armv7 platforms, where each build can auto-generate Visual Studio solution only for specific platform (qmake.exe -tp vc YourProject.pro). So it's possible to have separate .appxupload bundles (generated by Visual Studio) for x86 and armv7, but it's not possible to publish both of them in the Windows Store at the same time.
**Additional info**: On publishing of C# UWP application Visual Studio creates separate appx packages for all selected platforms(x86, x64, arm) and puts them into the one .appxupload package to be uploaded to the Windows 10 Store. But it looks like because qmake can't create Visual Studio project file for multiple platforms, it's not possible to use C# UWP approach. 
I hope that someone already uploaded to Windows 10 Store Qt apps and can share working way of doing this with multiple platforms support.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description, Qt5 WinRT provides separate Qt builds for x86,x64, and ARM platform, when you create package for your project, you may need to select one architecture at a time, like the screenshot below.
[image]

When you have created three different platform packages, you can upload these package and select apposite devices，different operating systems can run different types of packages.

Hope it is help to you.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense, it seems I have mismatched device type (Windows 10 Desktop, Windows 10 Mobile) and architecture of the package. I though that Windows 10 Mobile == armv7, but looks like it isn't.
Also it seems that Windows Store shows wrong package architecture information when new package is uploaded ... the architecture is determined as "Neutral", even if only ARM was selected during package creation as on your screenshot.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, but I'm looking for some kind of step by step description of needed actions to upload application packages for x86 and arm platforms with available Qt tools. Maybe I will answer myself once will achieve that, thank you!

Comment: Well, maybe your answer is correct, but it seems that it's required to have different packages versions for different platforms. Because all uploaded packages are determined "Neutral" and conflicts with each other.

Comment: Yes, so you need to create one package version at a time, then upload these package separately and select opposite platform. If you publish your application successfully, please share your way here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So far I was able to find only following solution:

It's needed to create different appxupload packages files to be uploaded into Windows 10 Store - one package for armv7 platform (where in Package.appxmanifest it's required to put target devices family as Windows.Mobile) and one package for x86 platform(where in Package.appxmanifest it's required to put target devices family as Windows.Desktop).

`<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Mobile" />`

Also the packages should has different application version.

Such 2 packages can be uploaded into one Submission application record at Developer Dashboard and will not conflict with each other.

In case if to try upload both packages with "Windows.Universal" as target device family, MS Store Dashboard complains that packages has similar "Neutral" platforms (even if different platforms were specified in app manifest). Also if both packages are of similar version, you will get web page error on finish of packages uploading.

In case if you will put the support of platform that is not part of the package, such submission will be failed during certification.